# Required visa category

Tags: visa, working-visas, canada

I want to join a postdoctoral position at Canada. In which category I should apply for visa study permit(from outside Canada) or work permit (from outside Canada)?? And approx how much time it will take to issue visa???

Comment: You need a work permit. Ask your host university's HR/international office for details, they should have detailed guidance and you cannot apply without their cooperation and active involvement. The approval timeline will depend on your nationality, background, country of residence etc.

Comment: I am from India currently pursuing PhD at IIT Patna. Can you help me furthermore??

Comment: You need to find a Canadian host university first.

Comment: Have you looked at the information here https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/work-canada/permit/temporary/need-work-permit-work.html?